# How does this color matrix make image black and white?

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, matrix

I am learning about image processing and saw an implementation for how to turn an image into black and white by changing the color matrix. Below is the implementation of such a function from [Craigs Utility Library](https://github.com/JaCraig/Craig-s-Utility-Library/blob/master/Utilities.Media/Media/Image/ExtensionMethods/BitmapExtensions.cs):

```
ColorMatrix TempMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
TempMatrix.Matrix = new float[][]{
                     new float[] {.3f, .3f, .3f, 0, 0},
                     new float[] {.59f, .59f, .59f, 0, 0},
                     new float[] {.11f, .11f, .11f, 0, 0},
                     new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                     new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
                    };
Bitmap NewBitmap = TempMatrix.Apply(Image);
```

I know from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix.aspx) article that the matrix represents RGBAW (red green blue amber and white). So, from my understanding, the colormatrix is multiplying each of the RGB colors with the array {.3f, .59f, .11f}. However I believe I am missing the last step.

Where do the constants .3f, .59f, and .11f come from that make an image black and white? How does this matrix multiplication make the image black and white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These coefficients are based on the human perception of color, this is the standard conversion from RGB to gray. See the wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale

Edit: To answer the other part of your question, the matrix is not actually going from 3 color channels to 1, it's simply setting all 3 color channels to the same value `0.3*R + 0.59*B + 0.11*G`. The matrix applies to a 5 channel image and it's not changing the last channels at all.

Comment: Thanks, I knew they came from somewhere, didn't know they were the general coefficients for human perception of black and white in a RGB model. So straightforward!